# how to filter with linq and `contains`

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I try to filter my items according to unknown number of filters.

//item.statusId is nullable int
//statusIds is a string

```
{...


        var statusIds = Convert.ToString(items["StatusId"]);//.Split(';');

        results = mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurations.Where(item => 
                  FilterByStatusId(statusIds, item.StatusId)).ToList();

    } 
    return results;
}


private bool FilterByStatusId(string statusIds, int? statusId)
{
    return statusIds.Contains(statusId.ToString());
}
```

But I get this error:
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean FilterByStatusId(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Any idea how to re-write it?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to look for the string representation of a number in a string, e.g. finding `"42"` in `"8976428934"`. Is that what you are trying to do, or is it something entirely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `statusIds` is an array then you can do:

```
results = mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurations
                        .Where(item => statusIds.Contain(item.StatusID)).ToList();
```

Some what similar to SQL `Select * from table where ID in (1,2,3)`

EDIT:

From your code it appears you have a string with semicolon separated values. You can try the following to get an array of `int` and later use that in your LINQ expression.

```
var str = Convert.ToString(items["StatusId"]);//.Split(';');
// string str = "1;2;3;4;5"; //similar to this. 
int temp;
int[] statusIds = str.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(r => int.TryParse(r, out temp) ? temp : 0)
                     .ToArray();
```

then later you can use the `int` array in your expression like:

```
results = mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurations
                        .Where(item => statusIds.Contain(item.StatusID)).ToList();
```

Comment: that's interesting (ID in (1,2,3)), what does it do if the list has 1000+ items?

Comment: @hcb, I am not sure, but I guess it would generate a similar query.

Comment: i need to convert statusId to string but I get the error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @EladBenda, why you want to do that, Your `statusIds` can be an array of `int` type and that you can use with contains in the expression, without using `.ToString`

Comment: @EladBenda, check the edit. I believe you have `;` separated string of Ids you can use the solution in the edited part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not insert the predicate statement directly into the where clause?

like this:

```
results = mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurations.Where(item => statusIds.Contains(item.StatusId).ToList();
```

you might need to convert the string array resulting from the Split to a List or IEnumerable to make this work.

---

The exception is pretty self-explanatory, the method cannot be converted to a SQL statement in the form you wrote it, but if you write it like above, you should obtain the same result and it will work.

Comment: i need to convert statusId to string but I get the error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @EladBenda Well, yeah, you shouldn't call methods within the Linq query because it will not be translated properly, better convert the string array to an ints, and then you can run this query succesfully